# Error "'function' object has no attribute 'tk'"

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am creating a label inside a window and I get the error

> 'function' object has no attribute 'tk'

I do not understand what is going on as I have option menus inside this code, and it seems to work fine without the labels.

Here is the function:

```
def taxesFrame():
    global taxesWindow
    global lowTaxVar
    global middleTaxVar
    global highTaxVar
    taxesWindow = Tk()
    taxesWindow.title('Taxes')
    taxesWindow.state('zoomed')

    taxesTitle = Label(taxesFrame, text = "Taxes")
    taxesTitle.configure(font=(titlefont))
    taxesTitle.pack()

    taxesDescription = Label(taxesFrame, text = "Set Your Taxes")
    taxesDescription.configure(font=(subtitlefont))
    taxesDescription.pack()

    lowTaxVar = StringVar(taxesWindow)
    lowTaxVar.set("Select Taxes for the Lower Class")
    lowTaxRate = OptionMenu(taxesWindow, lowTaxVar, *taxesList)
    lowTaxRate.pack()

    middleTaxVar = StringVar(taxesWindow)
    middleTaxVar.set("Select Taxes for the Middle Class")
    middleTaxRate = OptionMenu(taxesWindow, middleTaxVar, *taxesList)
    middleTaxRate.pack()

    highTaxVar = StringVar(taxesWindow)
    highTaxVar.set("Select Taxes for the Upper Class")
    highTaxRate = OptionMenu(taxesWindow, highTaxVar, *taxesList)
    highTaxRate.pack()
    return lowTaxVar, middleTaxVar, highTaxVar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first positional argument inside every tkinter widget is expected to be `master`, but here you are passing in the function name(`taxesFrame`) and hence the error:

```
taxesTitle = Label(taxesWindow, text = "Taxes") # Change to taxesWindow
taxesDescription = Label(taxesWindow, text = "Set Your Taxes")
```

Assuming you meant `taxesWindow` to be the `master` for `Label`.

Comment: so I set the labels to the function instead of the window... thank you Cool Cloud